# Why is a method not found on a reference to a generic type even when the generic type has a trait bound?

Tags: generics, rust, iterator

I have a function:

```rust
fn take_iter<
    LABEL: std::fmt::Debug,
    DATA: std::fmt::Debug,
    SAMPLE: IntoIterator<Item = DATA>,
    I: Iterator<Item = (SAMPLE, LABEL)>,
>(
    iter: I,
) {
    for (sample, label) in iter {
        print!("sample {:.?}: ", label);
        for val in sample {
            print!("{:.?} ", val);
        }
        println!();
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```rust
let a: Vec<(Vec<u8>, u16)> = vec![(vec![1, 2, 3, 4], 2), (vec![1, 2, 3, 4], 4)];
take_iter(a.into_iter());
```

Prints:

```
sample 2: 1 2 3 4 
sample 4: 1 2 3 4
```

My goal is to adapt this function to take the values by reference rather than by value:

```rust
let a: Vec<(Vec<u8>, u16)> = vec![(vec![1, 2, 3, 4], 2), (vec![1, 2, 3, 4], 4)];
take_iter(a.iter());
```

My current attempt ([Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b5518676c88e43da52ee59d61601e734)) is:

```rust
fn take_iter<
    LABEL: std::fmt::Debug,
    DATA: std::fmt::Debug,
    SAMPLE: IntoIterator<Item = DATA>,
    K: std::ops::Deref<Target = (SAMPLE, LABEL)>,
    I: Iterator<Item = K>,
>(
    iter: I,
) {
    for t in iter {
        let (sample, label) = &*t;
        print!("sample {:.?}: ", label);
        for val in sample.iter() {
            print!("{:.?} ", val);
        }
        println!();
    }
}
```

This gives the error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `iter` found for reference `&SAMPLE` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:30:27
   |
30 |         for val in sample.iter() {
   |                           ^^^^ method not found in `&SAMPLE`
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `IntoIterator` does not define a method called `iter()`.

Comment: @Shepmaster Would you happen to know how to improve implementation I have below? I can't figure out a way that `Iterator::Item` for generic `I` can work for both `&(SAMPLE,LABEL)` and `(SAMPLE,LABEL)`.

Comment: [The duplicate applied to your situation](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0316f7a397f5aa39feabe42fec12d5fc).

Comment: @IanGraham see above.

Comment: @Shepmaster Ah, thank you! It is difficult applying these advanced concepts to various cases. I appreciate your time with the help :)

Comment: @IanGraham no problem. I was close yesterday with my suggestions to use HRTB, but dealing with the associated type projection caused an error I was unfamiliar with. Luckily, there was a rust-lang/rust issue about it that linked back to dtolnay's answer on the related question, which made solving it easy. Then it was just a matter of cleaning up the usage of `Deref` and other little things.

Answer (score -1):

`IntoIterator` trait has only `into_iter()` method, not `iter()`. Also you have to call it on an owned value, not a reference.

In generic code you can only call methods of traits your function requires, and nothing else, so it doesn't matter that `Vec` has `.iter()`.